# Different menu items for Activity in debug and release mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, menu-items

For the application that I am developing, there are some menu items that are helpful for debugging the app (something like resetting counts and stuff).

Is there a way (a directive in xml file or else) to tell android to show/hide certain menu items depending on the app being in debug mode or not?

The only thing I know is the following code, that we can do in the Activity itself, I wonder if it can be used to show/hide menu items:

```
boolean isDebugBuild = (0 != ( //Check if the app is in debug mode
        getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

Or maybe is there a way to do this in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: you need do that in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` or `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your `AndroidManifest` application tag

```
android:debuggable=true
```

and in `onCreateOptionsMenu` check

```
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        //true for debuggable mode
    } else {
    }
```